# Big numbers in truffle test assertion

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

Here is what i've done: I have create a project this way:

```
truffle unbox react
npm install @openzeppelin/test-helpers
```

I have keep SimpleStorage.sol sample contract and here is my test file:

```
const { BN, expectEvent, expectRevert } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
const {expect} = require("chai");

const SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("./SimpleStorage.sol");

contract("SimpleStorage", accounts => {

  it("my test", async () => {
    const simpleStorageInstance = await SimpleStorage.deployed();

    await simpleStorageInstance.set(2, { from: accounts[0] });
    const ret = await simpleStorageInstance.get();
    expect(ret).to.equal(new BN(2));
  });
});
```

I get this error:

> AssertionError: expected <BN: 2> to equal <BN: 2>

I do not understand !
<BN: 2> is the same thing than <BN: 2> !

Which does this assertion fails ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be comparing the references of the objects instead of the data inside them. Try using the big comparisions of bignumbers the chai-bn package provides.

Heres an example from the package page

```
const actual = new BN('100000000000000000').plus(new BN('1'));
const expected = '100000000000000001';

actual.should.be.a.bignumber.that.equals(expected);
```

Here is a link to the chai plugin
https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-bn/

Comment: Thanks but what is the goal of ".be", ".a", ".that". Is it just for lisibility, this functions does nothing ?

Comment: yeah I think its just for lisibility, some kind of syntax trick theyre pulling to make it feel like youre reading the test in english. Im not really sure how it works, but I have something similar in my test suite and if you type it, it work so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯